# Dealing with Time.now in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Message` model and it has a `send_at` attribute that logs the time it was sent. In the console I'm trying to find the messages that are set for the future. Now I'm putting in the command `Message.where(send_at: < Time.now)` This is getting an error and I really didn't expect it to work. Does anybody know what the proper command would be for this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activerecord:

```
Message.where("send_at < ?", Time.now)
```

Mongoid:

```
Message.where(:send_at.lt => Time.now)
```

I am writing this off the top of my head but the idea is that.

Comment: Mongoid is irrelevant here :)

Comment: Thanks man you fixed my problem. If it's not too much to ask, could you up vote my question? I'm getting better at this but I still have Stackoverflow threatening to turn off questions.

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid asking that but I don't want Stackoverflow bothering me. haha

Answer (score 2):

Use the SQL-side query:

```
Message.where('send_at < NOW()')
```